# APTonCD load button does not work even after installing hal

Tags: package-management, aptoncd

I'm using APTonCD on my ubuntu 13.04 amd64 installation. I've installed hal, but the load button in the restore menu of APTonCD does not work at all.

When I run APTonCD through the terminal, this is the output I get after clicking the load button:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/APTonCD/restore/restoreWindow.py", line 205, in on_btnLoadFrom
bus = dbus_helper.DeviceList()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/APTonCD/core/dbus_helper.py", line 26, in __init__
self.hal_object = self.bus.get_object('org.freedesktop.Hal', '/org/freedesktop/Hal/Manager')
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 241, in get_object
follow_name_owner_changes=follow_name_owner_changes)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 248, in __init__
self._named_service = conn.activate_name_owner(bus_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 180, in activate_name_owner
self.start_service_by_name(bus_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 278, in start_service_by_name
'su', (bus_name, flags)))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Launch  helper exited with unknown return code 1
```

I can't make any sense about why this would be happening, and I would really appreciate some help

Comment: This is a bug. It should be reported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to downgrade to the version of hal used in 12.10 Quantal [download the Quantal hal packages from [packages.ubuntu.com]](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/hal). Uninstall the current version of hal [and it's 3 libraries]. Install hal-info first [I use Gdebi], then libhal1, libhal-storage1 and finally hal itself. Ignore warnings about later versions being available in the software channel. After this hal should load when you hit the restore button in APTonCD. Lock the hal versions with Synaptic or you might accidentally upgrade and recreate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using APTonCD to restore the backup of packages in ubuntu 13.04

Please follow these steps ( Load button won't work)

1. Mount the aptoncd*.iso with image mounter / open the file with archive manager.
2. Copy packages folder to $HOME
3. Type this command in the terminal

sudo dpkg -i $HOME/packages/*.deb

Wait until all packages installed.
You will get your backup restored.

(For this process you don't need to have installed APTonCD and HAL)

Comment: This broke the whole distro for me. A whole lot of dependency issues.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove that aptoncd from ubuntu center and download/install again from terminal using below command

```
sudo apt-get install aptoncd hal
```

Now check Load button works!, In my case worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is a  bug in AptOnCD. In fact, later versions of Ubuntu as 14.04 removed hal completely so installing hal is not an option. The bug report of Ubuntu 14.04 is at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/aptoncd/+bug/1175458 .

Here is a workaround:

- For iso files: Right click the iso file and choose open with-> Disk Image Mounter. For burnt CDs skip this step
- Copy folder packages from CD to Home directory
- Open the terminal and run:

  `sudo cp ~/packages/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/`
- Now your AptOnCD packages are in your cache. Whenever you install a package, your cache will be checked to avoid re-download, and installation will be offline if your AptOnCD deb packages are up to date.